# Nested Motion Component with React.CreateElement()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I have set up a component to handle my title heading tags with React.CreateElement():

```
import React from "react";

const Heading = ({ headingLevel = "h1", children }: HeadingProps) => {
    const Heading = ({ ...props }: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>) =>
        React.createElement(headingLevel, props, children);

    return (
        <Heading>
            {children}
        </Heading>
    );
};

interface HeadingProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> {
    headingLevel: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
}

export default Heading;
```

I want to nest a `motion.span` within the Heading component:

`<motion.span>{children}</motion.span>`

but this doesn't get rendered to the DOM.

I can get it to render just a `span` if I wrap the `children` prop instead:

`React.createElement(headingLevel, props, <span>{children}</span>)`

But the moment I convert the `span` to a `motion.span` component:

`React.createElement(headingLevel, props, <motion.span>{children}</motion.span>)`

it errors out with:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

What's the solution to make this work?

Comment: The code snippet you provided there actually works fine, even with the
`React.createElement(headingLevel, props, <motion.span>{children}</motion.span>)`. Could you share the exact line where the error comes from?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So I looked a little deeper with fresh eyes and the error seemed to be coming from my `Footer.tsx` component. I removed it from the tree the error went away. I then put the component back in and everything is running just fine.

I can still only get the `span` to render with `React.createElement(headingLevel, props, <motion.span>{children}</motion.span>)`

Thanks for pointing this out, I'm still unsure why I was getting an error in the first place.